# How can I see the UDS sessions?

Tags: stream, uds

Are the UDS (Ubuntu Developer Summit) sessions going to be streamed or recorded/uploaded at a later date? If so, where can I see them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The videos are uploaded to [ubuntudevelopers.blip.tv](http://ubuntudevelopers.blip.tv) and the [Youtube Ubuntu Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/ubuntudevelopers).

These are usually not in real time but the video team tries to get them up as fast as possible, sometimes as quick as the day after a session. The bulk of the videos will trickle in after UDS has started.

The [remote participation](http://uds.ubuntu.com/participate/remote/) page has a list of IRC channels for the event. These correspond to the rooms a session will be on [the schedule](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-o/). The topic for each IRC room will have an icecast stream of audio for the room. The IRC channel is displayed on the projector in the session as you can see behind this guy:

[image]

So you can listen over the icecast and type into IRC addressing the room and someone will respond to your comments by just talking and you'll hear it over the icecast. It works surprisingly well, I've had full conversations with people like this in a session before.

Answer (score 5):

**The Ubuntu Developer Summit** is the seminal Ubuntu event in which we define the focus and plans for our up-coming version of Ubuntu. The event pulls together Canonical engineers, community members, partners, ISVs, upstreams and more into an environment focused on discussion and planning.

**[Remote Participation](http://uds.ubuntu.com/participate/remote/)**

> We have always prided ourselves in
>   making the Ubuntu Developer Summit
>   accessible to those who cannot attend
>   in person. *Live streams*, *chat
>   channels*, *microblogging* and more
>   all bring the UDS experience to
>   everyone, no matter wherever they may
>   be.

Answer (score 2):

Last year the best source for me was http://ubuntu.mirocommunity.org/ as the feeds could be easyly be set up in Rhythmbox or Banshee. Dont know if this will work again next week.

Answer (score 1):

Possible location: [video.ubuntu.com](http://video.ubuntu.com/live/) It is dead at the moment but the UDS has not started yet.

For the KDE users Amarok has a script for the UDS on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/amarok-uds) and [kde.org](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=124463)
Even though this is a kde app and the streams seems to be from last year it might be worth installing it just for this event if there is not a Banshee/Rhythmbox stream. Hopefully it gets updated for 2011.