# Where can I watch Mark Shuttleworth's Keynote at UDS-O?

Tags: uds

Would like to see this years keynote, has it been uploaded yet?

Comment: see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40641/how-can-i-see-the-uds-sessions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here is the direct link](http://v2.cache7.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,oc%3aU0hPSlBNVl9FSkNOOV9IR1pJ&itag=43&ipbits=0&signature=60B5478FDA358D7E835852C141F078EEF0AFAFEC.6DE2F348F87263109A4B691A2D90BC40CDE231CA&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&expire=1305028800&key=yt1&ip=0.0.0.0&id=ae3c8d4c21d5cb1b&redirect_counter=1) to video in webm .

[Here](http://blip.tv/file/5121977) is the video on blip.tv

Answer (score 6):

It is now uploaded to Youtube on the official 'ubuntudevelopers' channel.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjyNTCHVyxs